# Why is Pillow only capturing half the screen resolution?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

When I attempt to capture a screenshot using Python Pillow it saves at half the resolution:

Here is my code:

```
from PIL import ImageGrab
def main():
    extraction=ImageGrab.grab()
    extraction.show()
if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

For example, my resolution is 1000x1000 px (just an example), but the image is saving at 500x500 px.

Comment: If you look at the actual dimensions of the image using the file properties, is the image resolution 1/2 of your screen resolution? Perhaps you are zoomed out on the image?

Answer (score 0):

It's working for me (macOS Sierra, Python 2.7.12, Pillow 4.0.0, 1280x800 resolution).

Here I add a step to save the image to file:

```
from PIL import ImageGrab
def main():
    extraction=ImageGrab.grab()
    extraction.show()
    extraction.save("extraction.png")
if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

And check it using ImageMagick:

```
$ identify extraction.png 
extraction.png PNG 1280x800 1280x800+0+0 8-bit sRGB 399KB 0.000u 0:00.009
```